# Removing duplicates from a dataset according to a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove duplicates from a particular column in a dataset depending on a value from another column. Consider this as my dataset:

```
A    B
1    10
1    10
1    12
1    13
2    10
2    24
2    10
3    9
3    10
3    9
```

I would like to remove the duplicates from column B, but according to values in column A. Something like this:

```
A    B
1    10
1    12
1    13
2    10
2    24
3    9
3    10
```

For a value in column A there should not be any duplicate value present in column B. I considered using *drop_duplicate*, but how do I instill a condition in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'])` should produce your expected output. In this case any rows that have both A and B matching some previous row will be considered duplicates and dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(np.unique)
```

But this instruction  doesn't return dataframe, but something like this:

```
A
1    [10, 12, 13]
2        [10, 24]
3         [9, 10]
Name: B, dtype: object
```